# ScrollSpy Not Working Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello guys I'm using scroll spy of bootstrap. I have applied some height and a overflow to make the scroll appear but after applying it the scroll spy does not works. I mean that when I scroll up or down the link in the navbar does not changes If I remove the style that I gave it starts working. Here is a Jsbin code. Hope this helps and please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    
<div style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  ..
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  ..
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  ..
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  ..
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  ..
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[JsBin](http://jsbin.com/qoretoc/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: You use this example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_scrollspy&stacked=h

Comment: @PareshGami yes I have used this just applied some height and overflow style

Comment: I just copy paste code from JSBIN when i am click on navbar link section is changed. so what is issue

Comment: @PareshGami yes that works but I'm saying that when I scroll up or down the link in the navbar does not changes

Comment: you have to make scrollable area with 200px only?

Comment: @PareshGami yeah I have to make it 200px a little more or less would not effect but it has to be near 200px

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106980/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-gardezi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're overriding the BODY scroll by using `style="height:500px;overflow:scroll;"` in the DIV that wraps all of the sections.

As a result, the BODY is never scrolled. You can instead put the ScrollSpy on this wrapper DIV..

```
<div style="height:500px;overflow:scroll;" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar" data-offset="50">
...
</div>
```

Also, the `data-target` should be `#myNavbar`...

<kbd>[**Working Demo on Codeply**](http://www.codeply.com/go/aJQjWqpgKI)</kbd>

Comment: can you tell me one thing that what does data-offset="20" mean

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Taken this example form the page - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-scrollspy.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bootstrap 3 ScrollSpy Events</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".scroll-area").scrollspy({target: "#myNavbar"});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.scroll-area {
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Bootstrap Scrollspy</h2>
    <p>Scroll the area below the navbar and see how menu items are highlighted automatically based on the scroll position. The items in dropdown submenu will be highlighted as well.</p>
    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"> 
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Scrollspy</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">
        <div class="section">
            <h3 id="section-1">Section 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>
            <p>Vestibulum quis quam ut magna consequat faucibus. Pellentesque eget nisi a mi suscipit tincidunt. Ut tempus dictum risus. Pellentesque viverra sagittis quam at mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio. Phasellus auctor velit at lacus blandit, commodo iaculis justo viverra. Etiam vitae est arcu. Mauris vel congue dolor. Aliquam eget mi mi. Fusce quam tortor, commodo ac dui quis, bibendum viverra erat. Maecenas mattis lectus enim, quis tincidunt dui molestie euismod. Curabitur et diam tristique, accumsan nunc eu, hendrerit tellus.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="section">
            <h3 id="section-2">Section 2</h3>
            <p>Nullam hendrerit justo non leo aliquet imperdiet. Etiam in sagittis lectus. Suspendisse ultrices placerat accumsan. Mauris quis dapibus orci. In dapibus velit blandit pharetra tincidunt. Quisque non sapien nec lacus condimentum facilisis ut iaculis enim. Sed viverra interdum bibendum. Donec ac sollicitudin dolor. Sed fringilla vitae lacus at rutrum. Phasellus congue vestibulum ligula sed consequat.</p>
            <p>Vestibulum consectetur scelerisque lacus, ac fermentum lorem convallis sed. Nam odio tortor, dictum quis malesuada at, pellentesque vitae orci. Vivamus elementum, felis eu auctor lobortis, diam velit egestas lacus, quis fermentum metus ante quis urna. Sed at facilisis libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum bibendum blandit dolor. Nunc orci dolor, molestie nec nibh in, hendrerit tincidunt ante. Vivamus sem augue, hendrerit non sapien in, mollis ornare augue.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="section">
            <h3 id="section-3">Section 3</h3>
            <p>Integer pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim. Donec sed nibh vitae lorem porttitor blandit in nec ante. Pellentesque vitae metus ipsum. Phasellus sed nunc ac sem malesuada condimentum. Etiam in aliquam lectus. Nam vel sapien diam. Donec pharetra id arcu eget blandit. Proin imperdiet mattis augue in porttitor. Quisque tempus enim id lobortis feugiat. Suspendisse tincidunt risus quis dolor fringilla blandit. Ut sed sapien at purus lacinia porttitor. Nullam iaculis, felis a pretium ornare, dolor nisl semper tortor, vel sagittis lacus est consequat eros. Sed id pretium nisl. Curabitur dolor nisl, laoreet vitae aliquam id, tincidunt sit amet mauris.</p>
            <p>Phasellus vitae suscipit justo. Mauris pharetra feugiat ante id lacinia. Etiam faucibus mauris id tempor egestas. Duis luctus turpis at accumsan tincidunt. Phasellus risus risus, volutpat vel tellus ac, tincidunt fringilla massa. Etiam hendrerit dolor eget ante rutrum adipiscing. Cras interdum ipsum mattis, tempus mauris vel, semper ipsum. Duis sed dolor ut enim lobortis pellentesque ultricies ac ligula. Pellentesque convallis elit nisi, id vulputate ipsum ullamcorper ut. Cras ac pulvinar purus, ac viverra est. Suspendisse potenti. Integer pellentesque neque et elementum tempus. Curabitur bibendum in ligula ut rhoncus.</p>
            <p>Quisque pharetra velit id velit iaculis pretium. Nullam a justo sed ligula porta semper eu quis enim. Pellentesque pellentesque, metus at facilisis hendrerit, lectus velit facilisis leo, quis volutpat turpis arcu quis enim. Nulla viverra lorem elementum interdum ultricies. Suspendisse accumsan quam nec ante mollis tempus. Morbi vel accumsan diam, eget convallis tellus. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="section">
            <h3 id="section-4">Section 4</h3>
            <p>Nam eget purus nec est consectetur vehicula. Nullam ultrices nisl risus, in viverra libero egestas sit amet. Etiam porttitor dolor non eros pulvinar malesuada. Vestibulum sit amet est mollis nulla tempus aliquet. Praesent luctus hendrerit arcu non laoreet. Morbi consequat placerat magna, ac ornare odio sagittis sed. Donec vitae ullamcorper purus. Vivamus non metus ac justo porta volutpat.</p>
            <p>Vivamus mattis accumsan erat, vel convallis risus pretium nec. Integer nunc nulla, viverra ut sem non, scelerisque vehicula arcu. Fusce bibendum convallis augue sit amet lobortis. Cras porta urna turpis, sodales lobortis purus adipiscing id. Maecenas ullamcorper, turpis suscipit pellentesque fringilla, massa lacus pulvinar mi, nec dignissim velit arcu eget purus. Nam at dapibus tellus, eget euismod nisl. Ut eget venenatis sapien. Vivamus vulputate varius mauris, vel varius nisl facilisis ac. Nulla aliquet justo a nibh ornare, eu congue neque rutrum.</p>
            <p>Suspendisse a orci facilisis, dignissim tortor vitae, ultrices mi. Vestibulum a iaculis lacus. Phasellus vitae convallis ligula, nec volutpat tellus. Vivamus scelerisque mollis nisl, nec vehicula elit egestas a. Sed luctus metus id mi gravida, faucibus convallis neque pretium. Maecenas quis sapien ut leo fringilla tempor vitae sit amet leo. Donec imperdiet tempus placerat. Pellentesque pulvinar ultrices nunc sed ultrices. Morbi vel mi pretium, fermentum lacus et, viverra tellus. Phasellus sodales libero nec dui convallis, sit amet fermentum sapien auctor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed eu elementum nibh, quis varius libero.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a some kind of bug trying to remove height and add min-height instead or take another div element and give it max-height:200px or what ever you want

hope this help http://jsbin.com/kubisivuwo/edit?html,output