# Bootstrap Scrollspy not working for backbone application

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I'm trying to use Bootstrap `scrollspy`. But it doesn't seem to be working for my application.

I've everything set as specified in the [Bootstrap Official Documentation - v2.3.2](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#scrollspy).

So, my body element looks like this:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".user-menu">...</body>
```

My application stack uses `Backbone JS` and the view gets populated by different sub-views. Eventually the DOM looks something like this:

```
    <section class="section profile container-fluid" data-section="profile" data-username="<%=username%>">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="user-profile-menu" class="span2">
                <div class="hgroup user-info">
                    ...
                    <nav id="user-nav" class="user-menu">
                        <ul class="nav list-group" role="tablist">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="#section1" class="user-menu-nav nav-link">Section 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="#section2" class="user-menu-nav nav-link">Section 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="#section3" class="user-menu-nav nav-link">Section 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                </div>
                ...
            </div>
            <div id="profile-content" class="span10">
                <section id="user-profile">
                    <div id="section1"  /div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </section>
                <section id="user-stats">
                    <section id="section2" class="stripe quick-stats">
                        Lorem Ipsum
                    </section>
                    <section id="section3" class="stripe quick-stats">
                        Lorem Ipsum
                    </section>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Other SO posts similar to this but not helpful:

[Bootstrap 4 - Scrollspy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601470/bootstrap-4-scrollspy-not-working)

[Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511045/twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy-not-working-at-all)

[ScrollSpy Not Working Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147577/scrollspy-not-working-bootstrap)

[Bootstrap scrollspy and backbone routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695767/bootstrap-scrollspy-and-backbone-routing)

Comment: It's probably the case when you are initializing the scroll-spy before the template is rendered. You need to initialize/re-initialize when all of the templates are rendered and present in DOM.

Comment: @DenisIvanov I've kinda reinitialized the application once the DOM rendering is complete. It is still not working!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? errors?

Comment: @TJ the `scrollspy()` function does not do anything. No errors. None.

Comment: @RushirajNenuji can you create a jsfiddle?